# How to filter data dynamically by supply values from form using django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to filter Blog Post objects or records based on the Post Category  and a User that uploaded the Post record, it gives me an error when I try to do filter, this is the error.

```
ValueError at /dashboard/filter-post/
The QuerySet value for an exact lookup must be limited to one result using slicing.
```

Here is my **models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Category Name')
    cat_desc = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.cat_name

    class Meta():
        verbose_name_plural='Category'

class Post(models.Model):
    pst_title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    pst_image = models.ImageField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to='uploads/')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pst_title

    @property
    def img_url(self):
        if self.pst_image:
            return self.pst_image.url
```

on **forms.py**

```
class FilterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=User.objects.all(), 
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    category = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(), 
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control js-example-disabled-results'}))
    catch_bot = forms.CharField(required=False, 
                widget=forms.HiddenInput, validators=[validators.MaxLengthValidator(0)])

    class Meta():
        fields = ['user', 'category' ]
        model = Post
```

on **views.py**

```
def filter_post(request):
    post = FilterForm(request.GET)
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    if post.is_valid():
        user=post.cleaned_data.get('user')
        category=post.cleaned_data.get('category')
        if user and category:
            queryset = queryset.filter(user__username=user, category__cat_name=category)
    return render(request, 'backend/filter-post.html', {'query':queryset, 'post':post})
```

I am having challenges properly filtering this in my views any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

instead of this:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(user__username=user, category__cat_name=category)
```

use this:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(user=user, category=category)
```

Also don't name your model fields after the model name, just use `name` instead of `pst_name` or `cat_name`, you will see that when you will try access these values there will be no confusion.

**UPDATE**

Ok, maybe try to rewrite your view like this:

```
def filter_post(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    form = FilterForm(request.GET) # its best practice to call your form instance `form` in the view so that the next line has better readability
    if form.is_valid(): 
        user=post.cleaned_data['user']
        category=post.cleaned_data['category']
        if user:
            posts = posts.filter(user=user)
        if category:
            posts = posts.filter(category=category)
    return render(request, 'backend/filter-post.html', {'posts':posts})
```

Comment: Yes, it is still giving me error, I don't think that method will work, because "user" gives me the username and "category" gives me the category. but in your own case user=user on the left is and integer and category=category the category on the left is an integer

Comment: I updated my original answer, check it out